# C weird behavior when working with char*

Tags: c

I've got this function

```
Function *function_get_by_label(char *label_name) {     
    int new_len = strlen(label_name) - 9;
    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char) * new_len);
    for (int i = 0; i < new_len; i++) {
        name[i] = label_name[i];
    }

    return function_get(name);
}
```

however, when I try to debug this one with gdb, like display the name variable, I get the following

```
(gdb) display name
1: name = 0x610120 ""
(gdb) n
1: name = 0x610120 ""
1: name = 0x610120 "m"
1: name = 0x610120 "m"
1: name = 0x610120 "mu"
1: name = 0x610120 "mu"
1: name = 0x610120 "mul"
1: name = 0x610120 "mul"
1: name = 0x610120 "mult"
1: name = 0x610120 "mult"
1: name = 0x610120 "multi"
1: name = 0x610120 "multi"
1: name = 0x610120 "multip"
1: name = 0x610120 "multip"
1: name = 0x610120 "multipl"
1: name = 0x610120 "multipl"
1: name = 0x610120 "multiply2_function"
```

How is that possible that there's such a weird behavior?
I tried to manipulate with these mallocs. I also tried to rewrite the function so I can give you an example how to reproduce it, but without a success.

Even more weird thing is, when I change allocated space in malloc to `sizeof(char) * 99`, the result is

```
(gdb) display name
1: name = 0x60f120 ""
(gdb) n
1: name = 0x60f120 ""
1: name = 0x60f120 "m"
1: name = 0x60f120 "m"
1: name = 0x60f120 "mu"
1: name = 0x60f120 "mu"
1: name = 0x60f120 "mul"
1: name = 0x60f120 "mul"
1: name = 0x60f120 "mult"
1: name = 0x60f120 "mult"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multi"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multi"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multip"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multip"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multipl"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multipl"
1: name = 0x60f120 "multiplyltiply2_function"
```

Comment: What is your input and your expected output? Also, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Input is "multiply2_function" and expected output is "multiply2".

Comment: You never terminate `name` with `'\0'`.

Comment: Even if I did, it doesn't change the fact that this for loop fills multiple chars at once, which I feel should be impossible

Comment: @JohnnyMopp is right. You never terminate your string with `\0` that's why you are having such weirdness (most of your memory is going to be null initialized therefore you won't have any problem, but you can't rely on this fact)

That's why you should use tools such as valgrind, they will tell you when you are accessing unitialized memory.

Comment: maybe use `print` rather than `display` ?

Comment: Buffer overflow in Stack Overflow :-) sorry couldn’t help. The ‘\0’ is indeed missing, that’s why.

Comment: @Neviem When you use the 'display' command, your variable gets printed twice per loop by gdb. 'display' prints each time you issue the 'n'  command, and the 'n' command will do at least 2 things (and thus stop 2 times) per loop in your code (copy your character and increment i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copy the string `label_name` to a new variable `name` that is 9 characters shorter. You copy all characters minus these last 9.

At this point, `name` is an unterminated C-string and all its storage has been used. In the machine's memory, there will be more memory after `name` but it is not yours and can have any data. Indeed, after you copied the last character (and your malloced memory was by pure chance zeroed), you see what is in the not-your-memory.

You pass `name` to a function `function_get`, however, that function doesn't know how long `name` is. If it would print it, it could print `name` correctly, or can print any data after it, until it encounters a null-character (*if* it encounters one at all; you don't know what is there). This is what is called *undefined behavior*.

When you allocate 99 characters with `malloc` you say it still shows "weird behavior". Indeed, because `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory so there could be any data in the memory. Although the memory now is yours (up to char 99), you still haven't terminated the string with a `\0` character and you still have *undefined behavior*.

Lesson learned: **terminate your strings with** `\0`**!!**

Answer (score 0):

You never null-terminate `name`, nor do you allocate enough space for the null terminator.  Also, there's no need to loop through and copy the characters over that way.  Since we know the source string is greater than the length we are copying, you should be able to do a simple `memcpy` (otherwise `strncpy` would be a good choice).  So maybe something that looks like this:

```
Function *function_get_by_label(char *label_name) {     
    int new_len = strlen(label_name) - 8;
    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char) * new_len);
    memcpy(label_name, name, new_len-1);
    name[new_len-1] = '\0';

    return function_get(name);
}
```